OPENROWSET: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
I need to execute a stored procedure on a remote server from a local one. I want to start by doing this with OPENROWSET because doing it through a linked server connection was giving me a bunch of errors. I figured it would be easier to start with this.
When I execute the code below, it gives the error in the title. How do I properly pass credentials so that it doesn't get stuck on authentication?
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI'
    , 'Server=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    , 'exec myStoredProcedure'
) AS a;


Are servers on the same domain etc? If not, you need to create an sql user and use it when doing the whole 'Server=...' string. There are plenty of examples on how such string should look

@siggemannen hmm not sure if they're in the same domain. How would I check this? There is a linked server connection from my server to the remote one, does that answer that question?

Well, why not use that one? If it works i mean.

@siggemannen because it doesn't work. It gives it's own errors, I can make a separate question for it

ok, you should put the errors in your question :) i suggest to start with regular sql login and then go from where. You can specify the login settings when creating linked server, tbh, it's usually pain to make windows auth work anyway

Does this answer your question? SQL Server returns error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." in Windows application

@siggemannen ok I created the other question for the linked server. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78281903/errors-when-trying-to-run-a-remote-stored-procedure-and-store-results-into-a-loc

@StrayCatDBA that question is for a client application. I am doing all this through SQL Server Management Studio

The fundamental problem is the same: kerberos delegation.  you are connecting to sql server A using windows authentication. sql server A needs to connect to a sql server B using your windows credentials.  it doesn't matter if using linked server or OPENROWSET, both errors are caused by the same problem.

Classic double-hop problem: you need to enable either Constrained Delegation or the newer Resource Based CD. And both machines as well as the user who is connecting need to be in the same domain. Contact your IT team for AD domain changes

@Charlieface can you elaborate on Resource Based CD? I don't know what that is. I searched for this and only found "Resource Database"

See https://www.patrickkeisler.com/2022/03/setup-resource-based-kerberos-constrained-delegation-for-group-managed-service-accounts/ and https://blog.netwrix.com/2021/11/30/what-is-kerberos-delegation-an-overview-of-kerberos-delegation/ basically flips around classic Constrained Delegation (CD) so that the service specifies the users/computers that can delegate to it, rather than the other way round. Pros and cons of each way, it depends on your security posture. Whatever you do, do not use unconstrained, it's insecure.
