Errors when trying to run a remote stored procedure and store results into a local table
I need to execute a stored procedure on a remote server and then write the results to a local table in SQL Server.
When I run this, it executes the stored procedure runs fine and returns the results in the grid:
exec LIVE.DatabaseName.dbo.myStoredProcedure

However, when I try to insert it into a local table using the code below, I get the two errors shown here:
insert into localTable (Field1, Field2, Field3) 
    exec LIVE.DatabaseName.dbo.myStoredProcedure


OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "LIVE" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".


Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 29

The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "LIVE" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.


On my local server, I have RPC Out set to True.
Whatever I do, I want to make sure that the LIVE server (the remote one) can't pull data from the local one because the local one is a development server. I want my setup to be where I can pull live data over to development but I cannot pull dev data into live.
Edit - does it make a difference if I only have a linked server object set up on the local server but not on the remote server? Also, how do I accomplish this without using an SSIS package?

You could use the SQL import wizard or work with SSIS package.

@Brad I am planning on running this on a SQL job because I need it to run nightly. Idk much about SSIS packages - would that help here?

If you use the SQL import/export wizard, it basically creates an SSIS package and runs that.  You can opt to save the package when you run it, so if you use the wizard and save the package it will give you what you need without having to do it yourself.

Check if the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is running...

@Brad ok so can I run a package via a SQL job? If so, then that would be the last piece of the puzzle.

openquery() might be able to do this

@JoelCoehoorn I just tried it and it gives this error: The metadata could not be determined because statement 'SELECT PART, LOCATION, ...' in procedure 'myStoredProcedure' uses a temp table

You can run the SSIS package from a job but you need Integration Services installed on the SQL server.

@BillRuhl the DTC is running on both servers

@Brad when building the query for my SSIS package, I got the same error as the one in my question. I put my INSERT statement (from the question) into a stored procedure that lives on the local server, then tried to use that in the SSIS package. What am I doing wrong here?

You can probably solve it by using WITH RESULT SETS declaration after procedure EXEC:
select *
into x
from openquery(yoursrv, N'
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  exec SomeProc
  with result sets ((part int, Location nvarchar(30), ...))')

With result sets avoid the "metadata" error because it declares the actual columns, so no FMTONLY metadata lookup needs to be performed.
Note that you might need to add SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of procedure and/or execution to avoid other errors like Cannot process the object "...". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "..." indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
